# how to include/insert HTML file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, include

Using Wordpress, I have the file `search-form.php` in my child theme's folder.

How do I insert this during a JavaScript routine from a file `404.php` in the same folder?

I've tried using: `<script type="text/javascript" src="search-form.php"></script>` but this does not output the contents of `search-form.php` at the place I am calling it from.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Use <iframe> or AJAX

Comment: a php file isn't JavaScript, you can't incude it like this. Iframes are terrible. A solution that will work everywhere is a Server side include (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)

Comment: You're entire terminology is wrong, which suggest you don't really understand enough to do the things you try to do. I suggest you learn first.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Amit.

Answer (score -1):

You could use php includes:

```
<?php include "searchform.php";?>
```

This runs on server side, wich is good for loading speed.

Or you could use iframes:

```
<iframe src="searchform.php">Old browser!!</iframe>
```

Or you could dynamically load it with js/ajax:

```
<div id="show">loading...</div>
<script>
body.onload=function(){
 //see ajax tutorials
 document.getElementById("show").innerHTML=ajaxdata;
}
</script>
```